# If I increase number of nodes in the hadoop cluster? will it improve my data copying to HDFS process?

Tags: hdfs

If I increase number of nodes in the hadoop cluster, will it improve my data copying to HDFS process ?

For e.g. I have 10 nodes and copying of 10 TB file takes 30 minutes in total.
Now If I increase number of nodes to 15, will it effect the copying time of data?

Similarly, if I reduce number of nodes to 6 will it affect the data copying process?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please edit the post and show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you add more nodes to hadoop cluster it won't improve your data copying.

Data copying depends on Network, Filesystem, Physical location of nodes